# How to hide google sheet url on top of the window?

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to use google sheet locally, not on the browser.
It seems like there is always a url on top of the window.
Is it possible to remove the url part? It looks unnecessary.

[image]

Comment: try with Adblock Plus to Block the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated google sheet icon from chrome and it doesn't show the url.
I don't know why it works.  :/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome. [**Download Chrome**](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=YTUH&gclid=Cj0KCQjw39uYBhCLARIsAD_SzMQIyuMTny4dSA0fE9PVDAzeCcZD3CBmuYbF-rABzGauVELFcf-oYjgaAii5EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) from this page.

[image]

Comment: I'm using google chrome.